# Create/Delete file using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel

I have an Excel file in `C:\testing.xlsx`. I am exporting data from my database table to Excel using `[OPENROWSET` (Transact-SQL)][1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) method. Now I want to

1. clear or delete all rows in my Excel file by executing some query in SQL Server
2. delete or create new Excel file in specified path (ie `C:\`) from SQL Server

Can I do this? If, please suggest me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I have got one very [useful link](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-excel-workbench/) which i have not tried. But, its a great stuff by author...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about modifying the excel file (have you tried deleting rows?).
As far as modifying files on the filesystem... if you enable xp_cmdshell you can run any command line commands on the system (like copy or delete).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use simple SSIS package to do that. Just create a new project in Business Intelligence Development Studio (VS2008) - it goes along with yur SQL Server installation and very easy to start.

Comment: I agree with Vlad. SSIS was meant to be used for these type of ETL activities.